# Run a function on multiple threads with a limited count

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Let's say I have a list that contains list of files I want to download and a function that gets a file URL name and downloads it. I want to download at max 4 parallel downloads. I know I can use a perfect solution for this:

```
        Parallel.ForEach
        (
        Result,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },                
        file => DownloadSingleFile(file)
        );
```

But what do you suggest if we don't want to use this method? What is best in your idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the "perfect solution"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a good old-fashioned `Thread` like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(()=>
    {
        try
        {
            while(working)
            {
                file = DownloadSingleFile(blockingFileQueue.Dequeue());
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptException)
        {
            // eat the exception and exit the thread
        }
    });
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: There are a few awesome things about your answer. Although its a little "old fashioned", I think its awesome and with a little tweak it'll be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

We may start 4 threads or use ThreadPool to add 4 work items.